# jfreechart не подключается в intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

пишу

```
import org.jfree.chart.*;
```

предлагает найти в web, соглашаюсь, выбираю версию любую и оно загрузилось. Всё равно пишет, что не видит.

Через project structure добавляю, и архив, и разархивировал - ничего не происходит. Просто отказывается видеть подключенную библиотеку.

Comment: никакую систему сборки не используете? Maven, Gradle? Просто с системой сборки эта проблема решается элементарно. И у вас ошибка в заголовке: chart а не chat

Comment: Подключите библиотеку (.jar файл) в проект через настройки проекта (F4) -> Modules и выбрать нужный jar или папку

Comment: Я нашёл и загрузил jar отсюда: [Repository Maven] [Repository Maven]: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.5.0/)

Comment: я испробовал все пути решения: скачивал вручную, подключал различные версии и т.д., но idea просто игнорирует ИМЕННО эту библиотеку

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/266694)